# How to await service ready Angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

Inside root component is ititialized first time singltone service.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private reonMapLibraryService: ReonMapLibraryService) {
}
}
```

Then in children component I try to get ready instance:

```
export class SearchFilterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   constructor(private reonMapLibraryService: ReonMapLibraryService) {}
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.layers = this.reonMapLibraryService.layersManager.getRegistryTree();
  }
}
```

It says that `reonMapLibraryService` is `undefined`, because firstly ar loaded children components.

How to await service for children components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to await the ready-to-use service or prefetch some data asynchronously before the app initialization, the best place for these is an [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER). An application should wait during the initializer execution and will start only after the initializer gets resolved. You can use it like this (let's put our initializer right in the AppModule):

```
export function init_app(reonMapLibraryService: ReonMapLibraryService) {
  return async () => await reonMapLibraryService.fetchData();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    ...,
    ReonMapLibraryService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: init_app,
      deps: [ReonMapLibraryService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

That's it. It should await the `fetchData` method execution and bootstrap the app only after it gets resolved.

Comment: It is not async it is just: `fetchData() { return this.mapApi = new ReonMapApi(mapContainer); }`

Comment: I try to initialize service from another library Angular, then I try to use this ready object in components of another part of Angular

Comment: Also I can not use export function init_app(reonMapLibraryService: ReonMapLibraryService) {}` because  I need to pass reference to templatw HTML as paramater for initizlization

Comment: Did you check docs of this third-party library? Maybe they initialize that service in some specific way?

Comment: As I understand, you can initialize and use the service in AppComponent with no errors? If you remove it from the child component - there are no errors? Could you also share a link to the documentation of the library you are using?

Comment: returning an async is the same thing as an async function